# i dont know why there is a visible top padding for leftbar?

Tags: html, css

I don't understand why that is like a gap for my left bar! when the code is the same for the right bar. the leftbar is working fine I think. just that I don't know why my left bar will drop down
please view the code full screen

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

.Topbar {
  background-color: white;
  height: 100px;
  width: 95%;
  margin-left: 2.5%;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

.Topbar .bigbigburger {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.Topbar .bigbigburger .Leftbar {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 47%;
  height: 100%;
}

.Topbar .bigbigburger.Leftbar ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.Topbar .bigbigburger .Leftbar ul li {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin: 0 0 0 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: darkgrey;
}

.Topbar .bigbigburger .rightbar {
  box-align: center;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 47%;
  height: 100%;
}

.Topbar .bigbigburger .rightbar ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  padding-top: 2em;
}

.Topbar .bigbigburger .rightbar ul li {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-right: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: darkgrey;
}

.Topbar .bigbigburger .logomain {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.Topbar .bigbigburger .logomain img {
  width: auto;
  height: 60px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 40%;
  border-style: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Main.css">
  <title></title>

</head>

<body>
  <section class="Topbar">
    <div class="bigbigburger">
      <div class="Leftbar">
        <ul>
          <li>BIKES</li>
          <li>ACCESSORIES</li>
          <li>SERVICE</li>
        </ul>
      </div>


      <div class="rightbar">
        <ul>
          <li>STORE LOCATION</li>
          <li>VIEWING SLOT</li>
          <li>LOGIN</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If the site is telling you that the post is mostly code, it means add an explanation. Repeating characters is not appropriate.

Comment: I don't understand. Your code *isn't* the same for both. You said the left bar has a gap but then said it's working fine? Your code could be simplified quite a bit but I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve layout-wise and your question doesn't make it clear. Instead of using filler text, please consider updating your question with a clear explanation of your goal so we can troubleshoot and give you an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `div.bigbigburger` is displayed `block` by default that is messing up your layout.

I'd propose you should make `.div.bigbigburger` become a flexbox with `display: flex;`

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

.Topbar {
  background-color: white;
  height: 100px;
  width: 95%;
  margin-left: 2.5%;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

.Topbar .bigbigburger {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex; /*Add a flexbox*/
}

.Topbar .bigbigburger .Leftbar {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 47%;
  height: 100%;
}

.Topbar .bigbigburger.Leftbar ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.Topbar .bigbigburger .Leftbar ul li {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin: 0 0 0 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: darkgrey;
}

.Topbar .bigbigburger .rightbar {
  box-align: center;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 47%;
  height: 100%;
}

.Topbar .bigbigburger .rightbar ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  padding-top: 2em;
}

.Topbar .bigbigburger .rightbar ul li {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-right: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: darkgrey;
}

.Topbar .bigbigburger .logomain {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.Topbar .bigbigburger .logomain img {
  width: auto;
  height: 60px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 40%;
  border-style: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Main.css">
  <title></title>

</head>

<body>
  <section class="Topbar">
    <div class="bigbigburger">
      <div class="Leftbar">
        <ul>
          <li>BIKES</li>
          <li>ACCESSORIES</li>
          <li>SERVICE</li>
        </ul>
      </div>


      <div class="rightbar">
        <ul>
          <li>STORE LOCATION</li>
          <li>VIEWING SLOT</li>
          <li>LOGIN</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```